# Ionic: Display image from http GET request

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, angular2-template

I am using Ionic-2, angular-2 and typescript.

As per my project requirement, i want to load all images in news page. For that, i should make http GET request to server and i get the JSON response. So now, i already displayed the whole data from JSON response in my view using angular2's `ngFor`. In JSON response, there is one of thumbnail property and i need to display that image. Thumbnail contains value: `/assets/images/News-Icon.png`

How i can do this. Any help will be thankful.:)

What i have done:

**.html file contains:**

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let news of news" (click)="newsDetail(news.id)">
  <ion-thumbnail item-left>
    <img src="news.thumbnail">
  </ion-thumbnail>
  <h2 [innerText]="news.title"></h2>
  <p>{{news.author}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using **data-src** instead of **src**.

```
<ion-list> 
 <ion-item *ngFor="let news of news" (click)="newsDetail(news.id)">
  <ion-thumbnail item-left>
    <img data-src="{{news.thumbnail}}">
  </ion-thumbnail>
  <h2 [innerText]="news.title"></h2>
  <p>{{news.author}}</p>
 </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: It's not work with `data-src` and yes, `<h2 [innerText]="{{news.title}}"></h2>` gives template parse error. It should be like: `<h2 [innerText]="news.title"></h2>`. Anyways, thanks for your time and kindly reply:)

Comment: what is the error you are getting on using data-src?

Comment: I am having my images under www/data/img/myfiles. My json value have "img/filename.jpg". I am getting my images using data-src.

Comment: It's not give error, but also not display an image. Error comes if i use `<h2 [innerText]="{{news.title}}"></h2>`

Comment: i have edited my answer for innerText. Are you getting your image displayed in browser using the link http://localhost:8100/assets/images/News-Icon.png?

Comment: Nope, so as per you suggestion, i didn't get all images from my JSON response if i don't save that images in my local folder??

Comment: What is the json value you have for image. Either it should have a link where the image is loaded or it should point to the local app folder where the image is saved. In both ways, you have to check whether you are using correct url. If the url is correct, surely data-src will work.

Comment: I understand the whole issue. I have to change the JSON response url path for image. Anyways, thanks for your valuable time and reply:)

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML as below and check it :

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let news of news" (click)="newsDetail(news.id)">
  <ion-thumbnail item-left>
    <img [src]="news.thumbnail">
  </ion-thumbnail>
  <h2 [innerText]="news.title"></h2>
  <p>{{news.author}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Thanks bro for your reply:) I already try with `[src]`, but it's not work with this. Don't know why! Have you any other idea about this?

Comment: Have you checked the app in browser and checked its console to make sure that its not returning 404 error for image URL ? may be relative path was not set correctly as per you directory structure.

Comment: Yes, i checked with console.log(); and it's not returning 404 error. It give me like this for image: `"thumbnail": "/assets/images/News-Icon.png"`

Comment: I mean in console's network tab you will see request sent for image and response their for that request. your image src url will be like `http://localhost:8100/assets/images/News-Icon.png` if not then you have to fix the is issue with URL

Comment: ok...but, what if images is not in my local `assets/images/News-Icon.png` and i want to get from only JSON response?

Comment: if images are not in your local assets and coming from any third party API then from their you must get FULL URL of image like `https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkZdt.jpg?s=32&g=1` without it where app will search for image ?

Comment: Yes bro, I understand the whole issue. i need to change my response for image like you tell. Anyways, thanks for valuable time and reply:) nd yes, `[src]` is not work as per your suggestion.